# Is it possible to create a method that refreshes a single vueJS component?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, axios, components

I have an axios call that is attached to a notation log component. When a new notation is submitted, it updates the MySQL database, but I can't find a way to get the 'notation log' component to update. I may be looking at the problem wrong. I have it working where the enduser can click on a  refresh button by forcing the url to redirect to the same page.

Comment: You should edit your question and include some code

Answer (score 0):

You **could** force an update to re-render the component, but Vue should handle that for you. If you submit the data into the database, the backend could return an updated list for example. Or you just send another GET-request when receiving the answer of your submitting-request and then set properties of your component.

For forcing a re-render, check out this article: https://michaelnthiessen.com/force-re-render/